# Print the Camera parameters from the file created after Camera Calibration

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have calibrated my monocular camera using the ROS Tutorial.
After calibrating the camera, a `.yaml` file got created which contains the various parameters of the camera.

**Task:** I want to print the coordinated of the center which are stored in `.yml` file. I think that i can do so by subscribing the camera parameter info but i don't know how can i do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140601/print-the-camera-parameters-from-the-file-created-after-camera-calibration/) by [rosqueries](https://answers.ros.org/users/6415/rosqueries/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rostopic echo /camera/camera_info
```

Change  'camera' to your camera name. This is really basic tutorial level stuff btw.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosqueries](https://answers.ros.org/users/6415/rosqueries/) on 2014-03-16**:
i want to get the parameters in my program. For example i want to print them using cout<<focal_lenght<<center_x<<center_y;

**Comment by [rosqueries](https://answers.ros.org/users/6415/rosqueries/) on 2014-03-16**:
So, how do i get them into variable in C++ program

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2014-03-17**:
See the publish / subscriber tutorial for creating a subscriber to a topic. Change the topic to the camera info topic.